# Install programs which require superuser permissions

Tags: tramp, install, sudo

I would like to, as part of Emacs Lisp package set-up process to run some programs which typically require superuser access, for instance, I would like to make sure that certain system packages are installed, and if not, then install them, I would also need to configure a database, which, will also require superuser access (once, in order to add a user with reduced privileges to operate on her own database).

I was hoping to enlist Tramp for help, but after some searching, couldn't find a way to do it.

Note, what I need is:

1. Make sure I need the permissions to do what I want.
2. If test comes out positive, ask the user to start a shell with elevated permissions.

From that point on, I think I could manage it.

Comment: [el-get's apt-get method](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/blob/master/methods/el-get-apt-get.el) does something like this, the idea is to run `sudo` directly (not as a shell command) and use a [process-filter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html) to catch the password prompt.

Comment: **Question 1:** Is detecting that login account is or isn't superuser sufficient?
**Question 2:** Will the shell be interactive or just run a specific script or command without any user interaction?
**Question 3:** Will emacs be running locally or on a remote server?

Comment: @Melioratus sorry it took me forever to reply. (1) Nope, detecting is not sufficient, I will need to run programs on user's behalf. (2) No need for interactive shell. (3) Emacs will be running locally.

Answer (score 1):

This could almost be it, except for the part, where I don't know how to make the shell buffer wait until the user finishes the interaction

```
(defun sphinx-install-prerequisites ()
  (let ((dir (format "/sudo::%s" (sphinx-install-dir)))
        (current default-directory))
    (cd dir)
    (condition-case error
        (progn
          (shell "sphinx-install")
          (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (insert "./install.sh")
          (comint-send-input))
      ;; Wait until the script finishes
      (with-local-quit
        (while (get-buffer-process "sphinx-install")
          (sleep-for 5)
          (accept-process-output)))
      (error
       (message "Installation failed. 
You may still try to read %s and perform the required installations manually.")))
    (cd current)))
```